# How do i remove something displayed from HTML table data without particular id?

Tags: php

I have the following code;

```
<td class="smallText" width="33%" valign="top" align="center">
<a href="#"><img width="100" height="100" border="0" title=" Genuine Value Pack " alt="Brother TN" src="images.jpg"></a>
<br>
<a href="#">Brother TN 240 Genuine Value Pack</a><br>
$325.00
```

Brother TN 240 Genuine Value Pack
    $123.00


    
    
    Brother TN 240 Genuine Value Pack
    $54.00

how can i remove the price in each td using php?

Comment: can you please show some more code, it is difficult to understand or just follow the link using html Dom you can easily do so http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: You may want to avoid such layout if you can (assuming this is your site). Tables for layouts are evil. If it's not your site, may God have mercy on your poor soul.

Comment: You need something to distinguish $41.90 to be able to select it from the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you could narrow your targeting down to a given dom element (for instance, let's say all your prices are in a div that you can specifically locate) then you could use a regular expression to remove the price strings.

This would be risky, as it would remove all prices in all areas inside the element you grabbed.

```
$myHtmlFromContainingElement = getMyDiv(/* sort this out yourself */);
$myHtmlWIthoutPrices = preg_replace('/\$[0-9]{1,10}\.[0-9]{1,10} /','',$myHtmlFromContainingElement);
```

Downsides of this:

- Preg replaces are slow, so you'd want to do this on pages that are cached/published rather than on dynamic pages, though that may be a sacrifice you are willing to make
- This will only handle Prices that match an exact format, namely "$NNNNNNNNNN.NNNNNNNN " or "dollar sign, 1-10 numbers, a dot, 1-10 numbers and then a space.
- This will remove **all** prices from the given selection.

Tested briefly on http://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html

Answer (score 0):

if you know the string that you are looking for, you could for example do 
    $find = "$41.90";
    $replace = ""; // empty string
    $myhtmlstring = str_replace($find,$replace,$myhtmlstring);

If you know it's in **td** tags, then you could use 
simple_html_dom (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) 
or 
symfony's dom crawler (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/dom_crawler.html) 
to parse the html and generate a list of all **td** tags. This narrows down the items you need to check.

You could also try to replace with a reg exp. search for "$" followed by nummeric characters.